# A finite direct product of Azumaya algebras may not be Azumaya?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Looking for an example, if it exists, of a finite set of Azumaya algebras $A_i$ such that $\oplus A_i$ is not Azumaya.

Comment: A non-trivial product of Azumaya algebras is never Azumaya (the center of an Azumaya algebra is the base ring).

Comment: What?! Don't we know that every Azumaya algebra is a finite direct product of Azumaya algebras of constant rank? This is a fact. Then, why do you day that a non-trivial product of Azumaya algebras is never Azumaya? 

Comment: You seem to be thinking of the case when $A_i$ is an Azumaya algebra over the ring $R_i$ and then $\bigoplus A_i$ is an Azumaya algebra over the ring $\bigoplus R_i$. Hence, the base ring changes. This always works so I don't know what counterexample you have in mind.